# Split column into two columns in a migration

Tags: postgresql

I'm pretty new to postgresql and have found some information on how to do this in a select but not a migration. I have a database of users with a name column that I would like to turn into first and last name columns instead. Here are some example names and how I would like them to be converted in my userinfo table:

```
name
------
"first last"
"first double last-name"
"first"
"No Name Available"
```

to

```
first_name            | last_name
----------------------|------------
"first"               | "last"
"first"               | "double last-name"
"first"               | ""
"No Name Available"   | ""
```

Essentially, I would like to split in a migration a name into a first_name and a last_name on the first space, with names containing no space having an empty string for last_name, unless name equals "No Name Available", in which case I would like to set first_name to "No Name Available" and last_name to "". Here is all I have:

```
alter table UserInfo
    add column first_name text UserInfo on delete cascade,
    add column last_name text UserInfo on delete cascade

--;;

update UserInfo
  set first_name = ???
  set last_name = ???

--;;

alter table UserInfo
    alter column first_name set not null,
    alter column last_name set not null,
    drop column name
```

Any help is appreciated including only partial solutions; I'm not really certain how to start.

Comment: Define the term "migration" in greater detail. Do you use any tool for that? Or are you loading files? Or do you build queries and execute them? Etc. From Postgres to Postgres or from any other DBMS?

Answer (score 2):

First create the user table with first_name and last_name as columns and run this with insert

```
select 
case when name != 'No Name Available' then
SPLIT_PART(name, ' ', 1)
else
'No Name Available'
end as first_name,
case when name != 'No Name Available' then
SPLIT_PART(name, SPLIT_PART(name, ' ', 1), 2)
else 
'' end as last_name
from users
```

Assuming users is the name of current table with name as a column

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` to separate the `"No Name Avaiable"` case, then use a regexp to identify the first name and second part of the name and call it in a replace part of `regexp_replace`

Here is the complete example:

```
create table UserInfo(
    name text
);

insert into UserInfo (name) values 
('first last'),
('first double last-name'),
('first'),
('No Name Available');


alter table UserInfo
    add column first_name text ,
    add column last_name text;

update UserInfo
  set first_name = case 
         when name = 'No Name Avaiable' 
         then 'No Name Avaiable' 
         else regexp_replace(name, '^([^ ]+)\s+(.*)$','\1') 
      end,
      last_name  = case 
         when name = 'No Name Avaiable' 
         then ''                 
         else regexp_replace(name, '^([^ ]+)\s+(.*)$','\2') 
      end;

alter table UserInfo
    alter column first_name set not null,
    alter column last_name set not null,
    drop column name;

select * from UserInfo;
```